# How to delete records from huge text file based on timestamp?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, ksh

I have a huge text file (say e.g. hugetextfile.txt) containing file names following the pattern like this (date is in format YYYYMMDDHH24MISS):

```
filename1-20130910120756.txt
filename2-20130910150156.txt
filename3-20130911190256.txt
filename4-20130912010756.txt
filename5-20130914020756.txt
```

How can I delete filenames from hugetextfile.txt which are newer than certain timestamp, e.g 20130912000000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -F"-" '{t=20130910130000;split($2,a,"\.");}a[1]>t' your_fle
```

Updating on your comment:
This should work. This command will replace the file and delete all the lines.

```
perl -i -lne 'if(/-(\d*)\.txt/){print if($1>20130910130000)}' your_file
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not seem to delete these filenames, it just prints these filenames from hugetextfile.txt

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i "/20130912[00-23][00-56][00-56]/d" fileName.txt
```

Comment: This generates an error: sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `['

Answer (score 0):

`var=`awk -F "-" '{t=20130912130000;split($2,a,".");}a[1]>t' hugetextfile`

for j in $var
do
        sed "/$j/d" -i hugetextfile
done
`

Here Variable var holds the list of filenames which are higher than 20130912130000 in hugetextfile. And for loop is use to remove those filenames one by one from hugetextfile

Regards,
VPK